# Creating Cross Matrix table with values in Power BI DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, cross-correlation

I have the following table (see below), where # Category per Client measure calculates how many MH+SA categories types are per client.
ClientID = 23 has only one category type - "MH".  Everyone else has 2 types - "MH","SA".

Diagnosis:

```
      ClientID  DiagnosDescription  [# Category per Client measure]
            22  SA1                  2       
            22  MH1                  2 
            23  MH2                  1
            24  SA1                  2
            24  MH3                  2
            25  SA1                  2
            25  SA2                  2
            25  MH4                  2
            26  SA1                  2
            26  MH1                  2 
            27  SA1                  2
            27  MH1                  2
            28  SA1                  2
            28  MH2                  2
            29  SA2                  2
            29  MH1                  2
            30  SA2                  2
            30  MH1                  2
            31  SA2                  2
            31  MH2                  2
```

Also, see colored screenshot below:

[image]

I need to create the following cross-matrix table in Power BI:

[image]

where:
Axis X = MH category type

Axis Y = SA category type

Value = a measure that calculates # unique (unduplicated) clients for each category pair - "SA-MH", where [# Category per Client] = 2

For example,

for SA1-MH1 pair we have 3 clients (ClientID = 22, 26, 27)

for SA1-MH2 pair we have 1 client (ClientID = 28)

for SA1-MH3 pair we have 1 client (ClientID = 24)

for SA1-MH4 pair we have 1 client (ClientID = 25)

for SA2-MH1 pair we have 2 clients (ClientID = 29, 30)

for SA2-MH2 pair we have 1 client (ClientID = 31)

for SA2-MH3 pair we have 0 clients

for SA2-MH4 pair we have 1 client (ClientID = 25)

My measure that calculates # Clients with 2 categories type combinations ("SA"+"MH") is the following:

```
    # Dual Diagnosed Clients = CALCULATE(
                          DISTINCTCOUNT('Diagnosis'[ClientID]),
                            FILTER(
                                   'Diagnosis',
                                   'Diagnosis'[# Category per Client] = 2
        
                                  )
                                  )
```

But if I paste this measure into my matrix, it shows the total number of unique clients with [# Category per Client] = 2, instead of calculating the total number of unique clients (Category = 2) - but accordingly to each pair - SA1-MH1, SA1-MH2  etc.

Please HELP either to update my measure or any advice (my DAX is only good for entry level tasks)

Comment: you'd better solve this on the powerquery side... @horseyride may help you with this...

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 new tables as follows:

```
MH = SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER('Table1', LEFT( 'Table1'[DiagnosDescription], 2) = "MH") , "MH", Table1[DiagnosDescription], "Client ID", Table1[ClientID]) 

SA = SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER('Table1', LEFT( 'Table1'[DiagnosDescription], 2) = "SA") , "SA", Table1[DiagnosDescription], "Client ID", Table1[ClientID])
```

Create a relationship on client id.

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Measure = COUNT(MH[Client ID])
```

Add everything to a matrix.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I'll try tonight and will update in a couple days!